# How to modify text "Showing x to x of x entries" in RShiny?

Tags: r, shiny, dashboard, shinydashboard, dt

I'm trying to change text: "Showing x to x of x entries" to "Showing x to x of x rows".
I'm using

```
options = list(language = list(info = "Showing _START_ to _END_ of  _TOTAL_ rows"))
```

however, I do not receive any result.
I put this function inside of DT::datatable.

Any hints what can I do more?

Comment: Can you show your full datatable code? I'm able to change the text as required.

Answer (score 0):

To change the *"Showing 1 to 10 of 100 entries"*, use the `infoCallback` option. For example:

```
  infoCallback <- c(
    "function(settings, start, end, max, total, pre){",
    "  return 'Showing '+ start +' to '+ end +' of <b>'+ total +'</b> rows';",
    "}"
  )
```

This will print the total number of entries in bold. And put it in the options: `options = list(infoCallback = JS(infoCallback))`. See https://datatables.net/reference/option/infoCallback.